# passing value of RDD to another RDD as variable - Spark #Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am currently exploring how to call big hql files (contains 100 line of an insert into select statement) via sqlContext.

Another thing is, The hqls files are parameterize, so while calling it from sqlContext, I want to pass the parameters as well.

Have gone through loads of blogs and posts, but not found any answers to this.

Another thing I was trying, to store an output of rdd into a variable.

pyspark

```
max_date=sqlContext.sql("select max(rec_insert_date) from table")
```

now want to pass max_date as variable to next rdd

```
incremetal_data=sqlConext.sql(s"select count(1) from table2 where rec_insert_date > $max_dat")
```

This is not working , moreover the value for `max_date` is coming as =

```
u[row-('20018-05-19 00:00:00')]
```

now this is not clear how to trim those extra characters.

Comment: Your `max_date` is a DataFrame, which is a `Dataset[Row]`, so this obviously will not interpolate as you are hoping.  You can use `collect()` and then convert it to a normal value to insert.

Answer (score 0):

The sql Context reterns a Dataset[Row]. You can get your value from there with

```
max_date=sqlContext.sql("select count(rec_insert_date) from table").first()[0]
```

In Spark 2.0+ using spark Session you can

```
 max_date=spark.sql("select count(rec_insert_date) from table").rdd.first()[0]
```

to get the underlying rdd from the returned dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use `max(rec_insert_date)` instead of `count(rec_insert_date)`?

You have two options on passing values returned from one query to another:

1. Use collect, which will trigger computations and assign returned value to a variable

   `max_date = sqlContext.sql("select max(rec_insert_date) from table").collect()[0][0] # max_date has actual date assigned to it
   incremetal_data = sqlConext.sql(s"select count(1) from table2 where rec_insert_date > '{}'".format(max_date))`

   Another (and better) option is to use Dataframe API

   `from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit
   incremental_data = sqlContext.table("table2").filter(col("rec_insert_date") > lit(max_date))`
2. Use cross join - it should be avoided if you have more than 1 result from the first query. The advantage is that you don't break the graph of processing, so everything can be optimized by Spark.

   `max_date_df = sqlContext.sql("select max(rec_insert_date) as max_date from table") # max_date_df is a dataframe with just one row
   incremental_data = sqlContext.table("table2").join(max_date_df).filter(col("rec_insert_date") > col("max_date"))`

As for you first question how to call large hql files from Spark:

- If you're using Spark 1.6 then you need to create a HiveContext https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables
- If you're using Spark 2.x then while creating SparkSession you need to enable Hive Support https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

You can start by inserting im in a `sqlContext.sql(...)` method, from my experience this usually works and is a nice starting point to rewrite the logic to DataFrames/Datasets API. There may be some issues while running it in your cluster because your queries will be executed by Spark's SQL engine (Catalyst) and won't be passed to Hive.

Comment: thank you sir for your kind reply, it should be max , as you correctly pointed out. I will try and let you know, I am sure it will work.

Comment: If I want to directly run the .hql file , can I do it with following command. 
 sqlContext.sql(open("file.hql").read())